# Disjointed Rollover fade in issue with image

Tags: javascript, rollover

I am working on a page layout where a text link at the bottom of the page will control a fadein rollover effect in a separate DIV.  The code I currently have allows me to fade in text (within the DIV area) when I rollover the text link at the bottom of the page. This Disjointed Rollover effect is perfect for the page I am designing - it has a nice fade in and fade out. However I would like to fade in a PNG image within the DIV area instead of text, and the existing scripting doesn't seem to allow me to do this.  When I try to replace the text with an image, the rollover effect doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to easily modify the existing code to achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance for your assistance!

The current HTML page I have is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var obj;
var speed=20;
window.onload=function() {
obj=document.getElementById('fader');
var l=document.getElementById('mylink');
l.onmouseover=function() {
fadeinOut('in');
}
l.onmouseout=function() {
fadeinOut('out');
}
}
function fadeinOut(dir){
if(obj.filters) {
obj.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+c+')';
}
else {
obj.style.opacity=c/100;
}
if(dir=='in') {
dir1='in'
c++;
}
else {
dir1='out';
c--;
}
if(c>100){
c=100;
return;
}
if(c<0){
c=0;
return;
}
setTimeout('fadeinOut(dir1)',speed)
}
</script>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">
#container {
width:324px;
height:200px;
border:3px double #000;
margin:auto;
}
#fader {
height:176px;
padding:12px;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity:0;
font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-align:justify;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="fader">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin massa. Nam vehicula.
Morbi velit nisi, mollis id, ultrices luctus, adipiscing sit amet, lectus. Nunc rhoncus
nisl ac enim. Maecenas vestibulum dolor ut velit. Maecenas condimentum pulvinar purus.
Pellentesque ac ipsum. Curabitur sodales, elit vel molestie hendrerit,
</div>

<a href="#" id="mylink">My Link Will Go Here</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotta recommend jQuery here. Look how much simpler your javascript is! And jQuery handles cross browser opacity for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( function(){
  $('#mylink').mouseenter( function(){
    $('#fader').stop().animate({opacity:1});
  }).mouseleave( function(){
    $('#fader').stop().animate({opacity:0});
  })
});
</script>

<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">
#container {
border:3px double #000;
margin:auto;
}
#fader {
padding:12px;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
opacity:0;
font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-align:justify;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="fader">
<img src='http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--owXoE04D_k/T-3epqrKyLI/AAAAAAAAANA/HLRMp2I9T4U/s1600/facebook-smiley-face.jpg'/>
</div>

<a href="#" id="mylink">My Link Will Go Here</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```